# Using map without knowing the initial keys, c++

Tags: c++, maps

I am trying to add up the times a letter occurs in a string using a map. I know how maps work when you initialize it but what I am having trouble with is storing each letter in whatever string is passed in and, if the letter has already been stored increment the count. So if the string is "hello", then the map would look like

```
   map<char, int> counts
   counts['h'] = 1
   counts['e'] = 1
   counts['l'] = 2
   counts['o'] = 1
```

There has to be a way to do this without having an option for every letter of the alphabet right? But every example online only has a way to use the map when already knowing what the key/value combo would be. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: just do `++counts[char];`, if key doesn't exist, it will insert one

Answer (score 0):

If a key doesn't exist, a value-initialized element is inserted, which for fundamental types means "zero". So you can simply say:

```
std::map<char, unsigned int> m;
for (char c : str) { ++m[c]; }
```

Then to report the counts:

```
for (auto const & p : m)
{
    std::cout << "Character '" << p.first << "' appears "
              << p.second << "times.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialze the map entries with `0`

```
   map<char, int> counts;
   counts['h'] = 0;
   counts['e'] = 0;
   counts['l'] = 0;
   counts['o'] = 0;
```

and increment on hits

```
   void count(map<char, int>& counts, char input) {
       map<char, int>:iterator entry = counts.find(input);
       if(entry != counts.end()) {
           ++counts[input];
       }
   }
```

Note this will also work well if the possible keys aren't known in advance if you simply do

```
   void count(map<char, int>& counts, char input) {
       ++counts[input];
   }
```

Comment: You never know what kind character will be in a string, hardcode it is very fragle

Comment: @billz I obviously didn't _really_ mean to hardcode input! That's why I've named the variable `input` ... (will clarify THX)